# problems with custom spinner width

Tags: android, width, spinner

I'm trying to make my edit texts and spinners on the right side of the my application aligned and all the same size but I can't seem to change the width of the spinner. I have figured out how to change the amount of characters are shown in the words in the spinner but I can't figure out how to change the size of the actual spinner. Any suggestions? This is my xml for my spinner layout:

spinner_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:maxLength="15" />
```

and this is how i'm calling it in my activity:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,actions);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the code as, It might be helps you.

```
 ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  month);
```

Comment: try to replace the (this,R.layout....) into (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,....)

Comment: Here the spinner width set with the text actual contents. Please try.

Answer (score 1):

change your layout_width & layout_height as "wrap_content". then it will change.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: @user1424489 if the following code solved your problem means accept the answer.....